# D3.js - Double click with many SVG element causes freeze in Safari and Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, safari

I plotted a large amount of data using D3.js.

At this time, when I double-click using Safari, the pointer will be loaded and freezing.
It does not seem to happen in Chrome.

In addition, this behavior occurs with code 1, but it does not happen with code 2.

Code1:

```
...
    Plot
    <div class="d3-map">
        <svg id="map_svg">
            <g>
                <g class="sample_dot"></g>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
...
```

Code2:

```
...
    <div class="d3-map">
        <svg id="map_svg">
            <g>
                <g class="sample_dot"></g>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div> 
    Plot
...
```

The program which I implemented is as follows.

https://bl.ocks.org/TaskeHAMANO/e259c3504f061c4c8f9af9628e8365c4

Is there a solution for something?
Any answer will be helpful!!

Comment: You're using the wrong technology here, this is a problem you should solve with canvas and not SVG.

Comment: @RobertLongson

thank you for your comment. It seems that it is better to use Canvas when the amount of data is large. I have never used Canvas, but I will try it !

However, why does not freezing occur by changing the composition of HTML?